# What is the difference let o1.prototype = Object.create(o2.prototype) and o1.prototype = o2.prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, assign

So I'm trying to understand the difference between `o1.prototype = Object.create(o2.prototype)` and `o1.prototype = o2.prototype`.

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308545/what-is-the-difference-between-using-object-create-and-using-assignment-operat), the former sets obj2.prototype to by the prototype for obj1.prototype, but I'm having a hard time grasping why you would want that (the prototype of a new prototype for example is just Object.prototype since the prototype IS an Object without further inheritance). Furthermore, it doesn't seem to quite work the way the answer to that question suggests all the time.

In the following code, for example:

```
function o1(){}
o1.prototype.test = "test";
function o2(){}
o2.prototype = Object.create(o1.prototype);
let instance1 = Object.create(o1);
console.log(o2.prototype.test, instance1.prototype.test);
```

both `o2.prototype.test` and `instance1.prototype.test` print `"test"`. So it doesn't seem to matter weather you assign the `o2` directly to `Object.create(o1.prototype)` or set the `o2`'s prototype to `Object.create(o1.prototype)`.

Also, if I'm understanding this correctly, according to the answer in the linked question, if `o1` is empty (which is it in this case) then setting `o2 = o1` would be the same as setting setting `o2 = Object.create(o1)` which would also be the same as

```
function o1(){};
function o2(){};
o2.prototype = o1.prototype;
```

Is there any significant difference between those three? Also, if `o2.prototype = Object.create(o1.prototype)` creates an *empty* object with `o1.prototype`'s prototype as it's own prototype, if `o1`'s prototype is not empty, then how do the members of `o1`'s prototype get imported into `o2`'s prototype?

Comment: "*I'm having a hard time grasping why you would want that*" - you wouldn't want it, that's right :-)

Comment: Instead of `instance1 = Object.create(o1);`, you probably meant to do `instance1 = new o1();` (which does `Object.create(o1.prototype)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you directly assign `Parent.prototype` to a child's prototype, they'll both be pointing to the same object. So, if you add a method, which only applies to the child class, Parent objects will also have access to them because `Parent.prototype === Child.prototype`

Example:

```js
function Animal() {};
Animal.prototype.Eat = function() {
  console.log("Eating")
}

function Human() {};
Human.prototype = Animal.prototype; // both point to the same object

Human.prototype.Drive = function() {
  console.log("Driving")
}

var animal = new Animal();
var human = new Human();

animal.Eat();
human.Eat();

animal.Drive(); // Animals shouldn't be driving
human.Drive();

console.log("animal instanceof Human: ", animal instanceof Human) // true
```

If you use `Object.create(Animal.prototype)` instead, it creates a new object with the `[[Prototype]]` (also, but deprecated, `__proto__`) set to `Anima.prototype`. So, if any methods are not found on `Human.prototype`, it will *fall back* to `Animal.prototype` (In this case `Eat`)

```js
function Animal() {};
Animal.prototype.Eat = function() {
  console.log("Eating")
}

function Human() {};
Human.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
Human.prototype.constructor = Human; // update the constrcutor

Human.prototype.Drive = function() {
  console.log("Driving")
}

var animal = new Animal;
var human = new Human;

animal.Eat();
human.Eat();
human.Drive();

try {
   // This will throw an error because Animal.prototype doesn't have a Drive method
  animal.Drive();
} catch {
  console.log("Animals can't drive")
}

console.log("animal instanceof Animal: ", animal instanceof Animal) // true
console.log("animal instanceof Human: ", animal instanceof Human) // false
console.log("human instanceof Animal: ", human instanceof Animal) // true
console.log("human instanceof Human: ", human instanceof Human) // true

console.log(animal.constructor)
console.log(human.constructor)
```

When you access, `human.Eat()`, first the method will looked up directly under the `human` object. If not found, this will be searched in its prototype which is `Human.prototype`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(human) === Human.prototype;
```

Since, `Eat` method is not found there, the method will be looked inside the prototype of `Human.prototype` which is `Animal.prototype`

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Human.prototype) === Animal.prototype
```

The method is found here and it will be executed.

---

Let's say you want to use `human.hasOwnProperty('eyes')`. It goes through the similar chain as above. If `hasOwnProperty` is not found on `human` object, `Human.prototype` or `Animal.prototype`, it will check inside `Object.prototpye` because

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Animal.prototype) === Object.prototype
```

`Object.prototype` has a method called `hasOwnProperty` and that will be executed

Comment: so in other words objects are reference types in js?

Comment: @TaraStahler yes. I have added some more info on the prototype chain logic.

Comment: okay, that makes more sense, and after doing some testing of my own, correct me if I'm misunderstanding, by a prototype's prototype is also a part of the original object's prototype.