# Difference between 'new person()' and 'prototype.person' in prototype chaining?

Tags: javascript, object, prototypejs

```
var person = function (name) { 
  this.myName = name;
}
person.prototype.tellMyName = function () {
  console.log(this.myName);
}

var person1 = function (name,age) {
  person.call(this,name);
  this.age = age;
}

//in below line where i'm inheriting prototype properties from parent, both new Person() or person.prototype works
person1.prototype = new person();
person1.prototype.tellMyAge = function () {
  console.log(this.age);
}
var person1Inst = new person1("sadmeer",18);
person1Inst.tellMyName();
person1Inst.tellMyAge();
```

Apparently i have to call  `person.call(this,name);` in child object constructor to inherit properties in constructor and `person1.prototype = new person();` or `person1.prototype = person.prototype;` to inherit prototype properties.

I wanted to know is that right to use just `person1.prototype = person.prototype` to inherit properties from parent as i have already inherited properties from constructor??

Comment: `person1.prototype = new person()` is NOT the correct way of inheriting. It should be  `person1.prototype = Object.create(person.prototype)` and then you have to set the constructor property of the prototype back to the original: `person1.prototype.constructor = person1`: [Benefits of using Object.create for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857)

Comment: `person1.prototype = person.prototype` is also incorrect because: [What is the difference o1.prototype = Object.create(o2.prototype) and o1.prototype = o2.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57127249)